# calling a wcf 4.0 service from jquery($.ajax)

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple wcf service developed in vs2010

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);



    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}



public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }


}
```

the following call is working

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client p = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        Label1.Text= p.GetData(5);
    }
```

but when I am trying to call it from jquery its not working

```
    $(".test").live("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetData",
                data: {value:'1'},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                timeout: 10000,
                processData: true,
                dataType: "json",       
                success: function(d) {  
                alert(d);                                            
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.status);
                         alert(thrownError.toString());
                    }
        });
```

can anybody pls help me coz its giving me sleepless nights.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the JSON passed over the wire (using Fiddler2 or the developer tools of the browser of your choice). I suspect that the JSON is passing the "1" as a string instead of an integer.

It appears that the problem is in your data argument:

```
data: {value:'1'},
```

This should not have the single quotes around it. The service is trying to resolve to a method with a "value" variable with a string type. Do this instead:

```
data: {value:1},
```

That should help the service resolve to the right service method.

Answer (score 0):

> Sir,try this

```
$(".test").live("click", function () {
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetData",
            data: "{'value':1}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            timeout: 10000,
            processData: true,
            dataType: "json",       
            success: function(d) {  
            alert(d);                                            
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                     alert(thrownError.toString());
                }
    });
```